# Django save() method won't save my forms and can't create a new instance

Tags: python, django, database, orm

I want to save 2 forms in my django view:

```
def create_model(request):
    context = {
    'form_one' : Register_modelOne(prefix = 'form_one'),
    'form_two' : Register_modelTwo(prefix = 'form_two'),
}
if request.method == "POST":
    form_one = Register_modelOne(request.POST, prefix = 'form_one')
    form_two = Register_modelTwo(request.POST, prefix = 'form_two')
    if form_one.is_valid() and form_two.is_valid():
       form_one.save()
       form_two.save()
       ParentModel.objects.create(name = 'mymodel', element_one = form_one, element_two = form_two)
```

The whole point is to create a new ParentModel which has a manyToMany() relation with both modelOne and modelTwo. But Django won't save it in my database this way. Does anyone have any idea why?
(also even form_one and form_two are not saved in the database with this method)

note: This is connected to my question in [Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839675/how-can-i-divide-the-request-post-to-fit-2-distinct-forms-in-django)

the forms:

```
class Register_ModelOne(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ModelOne
    fields = ['title_m', 'tasks']

class Register_ModelTwo(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ModelTwo
    fields = ['title_m', 'tasks']
```

Comment: What are `Register_modelOne`, etc.?`ModelForm`s?

Comment: Register_modelOne is a class form form, I will include it rn

Comment: Note: I have explained some details more thoroughly on the question in the link

Comment: Depending on how you integrated the forms into HTML you will only receive the content of one form, the one that the send action came from. So, don't expenct both to be valid if you have two `<form>` blocks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form_one` and `form_two` are `ModelForm`s, not `ChildModelOne` and `ChildModelTwo`s, so you can not use it that way.

Furthermore you named the `ForeignKey`s `p_modelOne` and `p_modelTwo`, not <s>`element_one`</s> or <s>`element_two`</s>. You thus should use the *result* of the form, and add these when you create `ParentModel`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_one = Register_modelOne(request.POST, prefix='form_one')
    form_two = Register_modelTwo(request.POST, prefix='form_two')
    if form_one.is_valid() and form_two.is_valid():
       item1 = form_one.save()
       item2 = form_two.save()
       ParentModel.objects.create(
           name='mymodel',
           p_modelOne=item1,
           p_modelTwo=item2
       )
    print((form_one.errors, form_two.errors))
```

In case at least one of the two forms is not valid, it will not save the forms or create a `ParentModel`. In that case one normally *rerenders* the template with these forms, which will, if rendered correctly present errors to the client. You can also print the errors on the stdout for debugging purposes.

Comment: Yes this works. I didn't know this difference between calling the method and calling the result of it's method. Thank you it was quite helpful